# Jest mock aws-sdk ReferenceError: Cannot access before initialization

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, aws-sdk

Jest 25.3.0

I am trying to mock DynamoDB dependency in my unit tests as follows:

```js
const { findById } = require('./mymodule');

const mockDynamoDB = { getItem: jest.fn() };
jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => ({
  DynamoDB: jest.fn(() => mockDynamoDB)
}));

describe('.', () => {
  it('..', () => {
    findById('test');
    expect(mockDynamoDB.getItem).toBeCalledWith({
      TableName: 'table-name',
      Key: {
        id: { S: 'test' }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Unfortunately, when I do that, I get the following error:

`ReferenceError: Cannot access 'mockDynamoDB' before initialization`

Strangely, if I do this, I can avoid the `ReferenceError`:

```js
const mockGetItem = { promise: jest.fn() };
jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => ({
  DynamoDB: jest.fn(() => ({
    getItem: jest.fn(() => mockGetItem)
  })
}));
```

but this doesn't suit my test, as I can't validate the params passed to the `getItem` function.

The actual code under test is fairly simple, it looks something like this:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

const toRecord = (item) => ({
  id: item.id.S,
  name: item.name.S
});

const findById = (id) => (
  dynamodb.getItem({
    TableName: 'table-name',
    Key: {
      id: { S: id }
    }
  }).promise()
    .then(result => toRecord(result.Item))
    .catch(error => console.log(error)
);

module.exports = {
  findById
}
```

If anyone has seen this before, or can shed some light on why the first example fails while the second works, it would really help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the unit test solution:

`index.js`:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10' });
const toRecord = (item) => ({
  id: item.id.S,
  name: item.name.S,
});

const findById = (id) =>
  dynamodb
    .getItem({
      TableName: 'table-name',
      Key: {
        id: { S: id },
      },
    })
    .promise()
    .then((result) => toRecord(result.Item))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));

module.exports = { findById };
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const { findById } = require('./');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => {
  const mDynamoDB = { getItem: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(), promise: jest.fn() };
  return { DynamoDB: jest.fn(() => mDynamoDB) };
});

describe('61157392', () => {
  let dynamodb;
  beforeAll(() => {
    dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
  });
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should pass', async () => {
    dynamodb.getItem().promise.mockResolvedValueOnce({
      Item: {
        id: { S: '1' },
        name: { S: 'a' },
      },
    });
    const actual = await findById('1');
    expect(actual).toEqual({ id: '1', name: 'a' });
    expect(dynamodb.getItem).toBeCalledWith({
      TableName: 'table-name',
      Key: {
        id: { S: '1' },
      },
    });
    expect(dynamodb.getItem().promise).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61157392/index.test.js (8.216s)
  61157392
    ✓ should pass (4ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   88.89 |      100 |      75 |    87.5 |                   
 index.js |   88.89 |      100 |      75 |    87.5 | 19                
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.559s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/61157392

Comment: Hi @slideshowp2, this looks great but I've hit an issue because in my code I've got something like this `dynamodb.getItem(params).promise().then(onSuccess).catch(onError)`. Using your approach, I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`. (I've updated my example above, just to be clearer). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @grigori Updated answer based on your update. It works fine.

Comment: you're right, I had a typo. Thanks a lot, this helped heaps!

Answer (score -1):

The main problem is:

Since your `mymodule` is imported **before** you declare the mock variable, it runs the mock snippet **before** that as well. That's why it claims your variable wasn't declared yet - 'cause when the mocked code is ran, your environment couldn't find the variable declaration yet, even though you - *visually* - see it declared before your mock snippet.

Another way of avoiding this error is by doing this:

```js
const {DynamoDB} from 'aws-sdk';

jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => ({
  DynamoDB: () => ({ getItem: jest.fn() })
}));

// At this point, whenever you reference DynamoDB, it's gonna be the mocked version.
// expect(DynamoDB.getItem).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: In other cases jest will complain that DynamoDB should be mocked with a function prefixed with 'mock'. So, this doesn't seem like a legit solution. Jest just seems buggy. I've done this in one file and it runs, then in another file it complains.